# Next/Previous button in Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, image, gallery

Right now I have a image gallery that changes images when a user clicking on a thumbnail image the appropriate div's style changes to block and the rest are hidden. I want to be able to add  next/previous buttons for additional navigation.

My thought was to use getElementByAttribute to find the only image with the 'style="display:block"', and then somehow add/subtract one to the div. But I am afraid I'm at a loss. Any advice?

Current code:

```
<div id="image1" style="display:block"><img src="resources/images/larges/01.jpg"></div>
<div id="image2" style="display:none"><img src="resources/images/larges/02.jpg"></div>
. . .

<img style='cursor:pointer;' onclick="showDiv(1)" src="resources/images/thumbs/01.jpg">
<img style='cursor:pointer;' onclick="showDiv(2)" src="resources/images/thumbs/02.jpg">
. . .

<script type = "text/javascript">       
   function showDiv(which) {
    for(i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
       document.getElementById("image"+i).style.display="none";
    }
       document.getElementById("image" + which).style.display = "block";
    }   
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can declare a global variable

```
var currentImage = 1; //assuming the 1st image shown is always the first
```

then, you add two buttons,

```
<button type="button" onclick="showDiv(currentImage - 1)">Previous</button>
<button type="button" onclick="showDiv(currentImage + 1)">Next</button>
```

on your function you update the currentImage with the given param

```
function showDiv(which) {
   for(i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
      document.getElementById("image"+i).style.display="none";
   }
   //in the next 2 lines, you make sure which isn't lower than 1, and isn't greater than the number of images
   if(which < 1) which = 1;
   if(which > 13) which = 13;
   document.getElementById("image" + which).style.display = "block";
   currentImage = which;
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm, unless I'm missing something I don't think this one will work. My "onclick" attribute needs to supply the function with an integer.

Comment: Small modification so that the gallery loops around.
    if(which < 1) which = 13;
    if(which > 13) which = 11;

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you only use one div for the displaying the large one? (**This is with jquery support**)

The idea is to change the only image you want to display and not just hide the others. You can save the actual as attribute for the next button (allowed if they start with data-)

```
<div style="display:block"><img  id="largeimg" data-nr="1" src="resources/images/larges/01.jpg"></div>
<img data-nr="1" class="clickable" style='cursor:pointer;' src="resources/images/thumbs/01.jpg">
<img data-nr="2" class="clickable" style='cursor:pointer;' src="resources/images/thumbs/02.jpg">
. . .

<script type = "text/javascript">       
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickable").each(function({
      this.click(function(){
         $("#largeimg").attr("src",this.attr("src")).attr("data-nr",this.attr("data-nr"));
      }
    }
  });
  function nextpic() {
    newid = parseInt($("#largeimg").attr("data-nr"))+1;
    newsrc = $(".clickable[data-nr="+newid+"]").attr("src");
    $("#largeimg").attr("src",newsrc).attr("data-nr",newid);
  }
</script>
```

EDIT: Because he said it should be for videos too: http://jsfiddle.net/x6W8m/
isn't perfect but should show a bit :)

Comment: I would except one of my divs is a <video> tag instead of an image.
Sorry, I should've included that information... AND it stack overflow won't let me edit my post. :(

Comment: oh okay, works nearly equal! Will post it soon, need some more time :)

Comment: No objections to jQuery whatsoever.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x6W8m/ - there is only a problem with playing the video, but you can handle this :) @ENev - If this was helpful, i hope you give me the "correct answer" flag :)

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript, declare a global variable `i`, which signifies which div is currently visible (in your code above, for example, it is '`imagei`'). When a user clicks on a thumbnail of div `image4`, say, set `i` to `4` and so on.

Now for the previous/next buttons, you already know the current value of `i`, so you know which div is being displayed. Increment or decrement `i` now to show the next div in the sequence.

And in case you want to use only one div, [here's a blog post](http://1lifeisallwegot.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/javascript-slideshow-code/) from where you can copy the whole javascript code for the gallery, including next/previous buttons.

Comment: I'm not sure how to have my script know which one is visible. Any suggestions on a function?

Comment: The second sentence of my answer tells you how.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Next and Previous Button</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>

<img src="images.jpg" id="imgDemo" alt="HTML5 Icon" width="128" height="128"> 

                <button onclick="nxt()" id="btnOne">next</button>
                <button onclick="prvs()" id="btnTwo">previous</button> 

<script>

var img = new Array("images.jpg","images1.jpg","images2.jpg","images3.jpg","images4.jpg","images5.jpg","images6.jpg","images7.jpg","images8.jpg");

var imgElement = document.getElementById("imgDemo");
var i = 0;
var imgLen = img.length;

        function nxt()
        {
            if(i < imgLen-1)
                {
                    i++;
                }
            else{
                    i=0;                
                }

                imgElement.src = img[i];                    
        }

        function prvs()
        {
            if(i > 0)
                {
                    i--;
                }
            else
            {
                i = imgLen-1;
            }
                imgElement.src = img[i];                    
        }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```